# Visual Studio cross compiling with gcc/gdb within vmware -> memory access error

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio, cross-compiling

I have configured visual studio to compile my files via GCC within Linux over the new Linux compiler feature (cross compiling).

Everything works: VS compiles and also creates the correct files on my hosting Linux system. So I have created a virtual machine. I am now facing the problem that I don't have access to the virtual machines memory I guess.

This message pops up every time I try to run my program:

### Programm

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

### Message

```
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x530
```

I thought oh well I just need to run visual studio as admin but did not work.

Comment: vmware is not a compiler! So you compiled the source code of Visual-Studio?

Comment: Of course not. As you have read my question I have set up a virtual machine running Linux. Visual studio remotely compiles the files via gcc...

Comment: You should read your headline: "Visual Studio cross compiling with ...". And pick the language you use. C and C++ are different languages!

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Didn't knew that. I have tried both languages and they both produce this error.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, VCLinux is not a cross-compiler, it simply builds and executes an application on a target Linux system under the control of Visual Studio. There is no need to run as administrator on the Windows host or root on the Linux target (unless your application needs root permissions and even then it's something to to avoid).

Is there a difference between the "hosting Linux system" and the "virtual machine" you created. I would expect them to be one and the same but the order in which you refer to them is unusual.

You say that your Visual Studio project is building under VCLinux. So, on the Linux target, was a directory for the project created with a sub-directory `bin/x32/Debug` (or `bin/x64/Debug`) with an executable `<project name>.out` (or similar)? In which case all the basic connecting and communication is working fine.
What happens when you log on to the Linux system and run that executable 1)directly from the command line and 2)under gdb ?

Did you set the project as the VS `Startup Project` (right-click on project)? Does the "debug" button on the VS toolbar show `Remote GDB Debugger`?

Comment: Oh okay ^^ I think I mixed it with the "cross platform" tab within vs. Yes, for testing purposes I have created a "hello world" program and when I click on Remote GDB Debugger it builds throws the error but I can run it on my Linux machine.

Comment: In the project properties page, Debugging tab, would you try changing the `Debugging Mode` from `gdbserver` to `gdb`, start the application and capture the contents of the Output/Debug window then post them here.

Comment: Oh very weird, now it's working with gdb. c++ and c code. C code also with gcc. I can also set breakpoints.Is there something I am missing like starting the gdbserver or something else?

Comment: gdbserver uses port 4444

Comment: finger trouble ...
does your Linux system have a firewall of other reason why a network port might be blocked? gdd goes over the ssh connection and therefore uses port 22 which is also used for building and you clearly have open and working. gdbserver uses another free port, usually 4444 but VCLinux could pick another.
Try setting the `Debugger Port Number` in the project properties/Debugging page to a port on the Linux target you know to be open and running with gdbserver again.

Comment: I have edit the debugging settings with port = 4444. Then I have written a new entry into iptables to open port 4444 but it still doesn't work. I have also manual disabled my host (windows) firewall.

Comment: Then you've got me stumped. But at least you can debug in gdb mode. If you like, you can write up exactly what your system configuration looks like and raise it as an issue on the VCLinux project GitHub site: [https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux]

Comment: Thanks for your help! ... Yea maybe I will do. I tested it with a bananapi running Debian and it works. Even with gdbserver, so maybe it's because of using VMware. Might be a bug or so.